# Using Zend Optimizer+ with php-fpm + nginx

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, zend-server, zend

Note: I am talking about a component previously in Zend Server, but is now a standalone module and [open-sourced](https://github.com/zend-dev/ZendOptimizerPlus), and will be bundle with [PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/optimizerplus), it has performance/usability edge over the more widely used APC.

Now here is my problem, I cannot seem to get Zend Optimizer+ work properly with my codeigniter-powered (PHP framework) site, my debug config is as following:

```
zend_optimizerplus.enable=1
zend_optimizerplus.memory_consumption=128
zend_optimizerplus.interned_strings_buffer=8
zend_optimizerplus.max_accelerated_files=4000
zend_optimizerplus.revalidate_freq=10
zend_optimizerplus.fast_shutdown=1
zend_optimizerplus.enable_cli=1
zend_optimizerplus.optimization_level=0
zend_optimizerplus.error_log=/var/log/zendop.log
```

Once ZO+ is enabled, I started to see php-fpm logs such as these (but nothing else, no segfault error, no entries in ZO+ error log):

```
[13-Mar-2013 00:58:45] WARNING: [pool www] child 6734 exited with code 1 after 176.326628 seconds from start
[13-Mar-2013 00:58:45] NOTICE: [pool www] child 6761 started
```

Basically php worker process were stopped and restarted. And all page appear to be outputing only partially. I turned on php error display with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` but still don't see any error from PHP itself.

All I can find in Nginx log were entries like:

```
2013/03/13 00:22:47 [error] 1761#0: *14 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: [my ip address], server: [my server name], request: "GET /leave HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: [my host name].

2013/03/13 00:22:47 [error] 1761#0: *17 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: [my ip address], server: [my server name], request: "GET /leave HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: [my host name].
```

I can't seem to find much insight regarding what were happening, and I can confirm the site works without ZO+ fine, and ZO+ source appear to compile and install correctly (make test also passed correctly, though there aren't many tests to run).

**Anyone had experience with Zend Optimizer+?** I am surprised to see no mention of soon-to-be PHP-bundled module anywhere on this site.

`php -v`

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 18 2013 23:40:19)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

`nginx -v`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
```

(If this post belongs to stackoverflow, please help to migrate, though I am not seeing a programming-related error here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing with PHP 5.3/5.4 without the Suhosin patch, I can confirm the original issue is indeed caused by Suhosin, and unfortunately, the common workaround `suhosin.simulation = On` will not fix such incompatibility with Zend O+.

Details can be found in this github ticket: https://github.com/zend-dev/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/63, in case you are interested.